# Difficulty linking MPI library

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi

After considerable effort I almost have an MPI environment running on my server. The MPI environment is hosted by anaconda. I am trying to compile a simple MPI program -

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

/*MPI Stuff*/
  int ierr;
  int m, id;
  ierr = MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );

  if ( ierr != 0 )
    {
      //std::cout << "\n";
      //std::cout << "HELLO_MPI - Fatal error!\n";
      //std::cout << "  MPI_Init returned nonzero ierr.\n";
      exit ( 1 );
    }

  ierr = MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &m );
  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id );

}
```

I try and compile like this -

```
mpic++  mpi.cc -o mpi  -g -lpthread
```

But the linker complains -

```
mpic++  mpi.cc -o mpi  -g -lpthread 
/home/rajatkmitra/anaconda3.2020.11/envs/cc_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: 
/home/rajatkmitra/anaconda3.2020.11/envs/cc_env/lib/./libz.so.1: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
/home/rajatkmitra/anaconda3.2020.11/envs/cc_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: 
/home/rajatkmitra/anaconda3.2020.11/envs/cc_env/lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `aligned_alloc@GLIBC_2.16'
/home/rajatkmitra/anaconda3.2020.11/envs/cc_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: 
/home/rajatkmitra/anaconda3.2020.11/envs/cc_env/lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: build] Error 1
```

I also tried including a versioning file (version.cc) -

```
__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.14");
__asm__(".symver aligned_alloc,aligned_alloc@GLIBC_2.16");
__asm__(".symver clock_gettime,clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17");
mpic++  mpi.cc -o mpi  -g -lpthread
```

Included this in mpi.cc
#include "version.cc"

but no luck here. Anyone knows how to fix this??

Comment: 1. Do `which mpic++` to confirm that it belong with anaconda. 2. Why anaconda? That's a python environment, which is irrelevant for you. 3. Can you use an ordinary package manager (brew, yum, whatever) to install mpi? You could even download mpich and compile it yourself.

Comment: Excellent point Victor... I just determined that mpic++ is actually in /usr/local/bin but is trying to use the mpi libraries from the anaconda install. I see the mpi library under /usr/local/lib64. Any ideas how I can force mpic++ (/usr/local/bin) to use the proper library instead of that from the anaconda install??